# Trouble understanding equation from density functional theory

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, density-functional-theory

In the review by Oliviera *et. al.*, I do not understand how the authors get equation 14:
\begin{equation} 
E[\rho]=\sum_i^Mn_i\langle\Psi_i|-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2+v_{ext}(\vec{r})+\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{\rho(\vec{r'})}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r'}|}|\Psi_i\rangle+E_{xc}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_\beta^N\sum_{\beta\neq\alpha}^N\frac{Z_\alpha Z_\beta}{|\vec{R_\alpha}-\vec{R_\beta}|}\tag{14.}
\end{equation}
 To me the energy should be in this form:

$$E = \langle\psi|T + V_\mathrm{ext} + V_\mathrm{ee}|\psi\rangle$$

How did they manage to put some of term out of the bracket? I also have trouble retrieving (16) as they cite, are they using a Taylor expansion?

#### References:

1. Oliveira, A. F.; Seifert, G.; Heine, T.; Duarte, H. A. Density-functional based tight-binding: an approximate DFT method. *J. Braz. Chem. Soc.* **2009,** *20* (7), 1193–1205. [DOI: 10.1590/S0103-50532009000700002](https://doi.org/10.1590/S0103-50532009000700002).

Comment: Could you please duplicate equations (14) and (16) in your question, as well as add some context and define all the variables in case the full-text article becomes unavailable?

Comment: I think they pull E_xc[\rho] out of bracket because it is a functional. V_ee is composed of coulombic and exchange interaction right, the coloumbic term can be calculated represented easily with the 1-RDM (?) operator, whereas the exchange is more complicated so they pulled it out for simplicity.